# The error code of SSL_read function stucked me

Tags: c, openssl

```
sslread_result=SSL_read(ssl,...);
sslread_err=SSL_get_error(ssl,sslread_result);
if(sslread_err==SSL_ERROR_NONE) {
    //...
}
else if(sslread_err==SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ||sslread_err==SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
    //...
}
else {
    printf("0x%08X:[ERROR!]-WSARecv-Decipher/SSL_read error:%d/%d\n",GetCurrentThreadId(),sslread_err,sslread_result);
    
    char err_msg[1024]="";
    printf("SSL read error(%d):%s\n%s\n%s\n",
           sslread_err,
           ERR_error_string(sslread_err,err_msg),
           err_msg,
           ERR_reason_error_string(sslread_err)); 

}
```

I was using openssl to send https request and get response. Somehow it went wrong. The error output was like this(print by the function `printf`):

0x00001E78:[ERROR!]-WSARecv-Decipher/SSL_read error:6/0
SSL read error(6):error:00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib
error:00000006:lib(0):func(0):EVP lib
EVP lib

What does this mean? the errorcode of openssl 0000006, and the error string `EVP lib`.

Answer (score 0):

From your output I can see the `SSL_get_error()` is returning the value 6 - which is actually `SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN`. The man page has this to say about it:

```
SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN

The TLS/SSL peer has closed the connection for writing by sending the close_notify alert. No more data can be read. Note that SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN does not necessarily indicate that the underlying transport has been closed.
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html

So the remote peer closed the connection down cleanly.

You *cannot* pass your `sslread_err` value to `ERR_error_string`. That will give you an incorrect error message as you discovered.

If SSL_get_error() indicates a fatal error via `SSL_ERROR_SSL` then you may be able to get more details on the error using `ERR_get_error`. You can pass *that* value to `ERR_error_string`. See the man pages on the `ERR` functions here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ERR_get_error.html
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ERR_error_string.html